# Accessing memory with various types through a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, constraints, undefined-behavior

I know that using a union eliminates the worry of undefined behavior issues when accessing the same block of memory with different types, one at a time.

I was wondering if the same is true for memory allocated with `malloc()` and a void pointer; does the following code exhibit any form of undefined behavior or violate any constraint?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union memblk {
    int x;
    double y;
    long long z;
} memblk;

int main(void)
{
    /*
    TYPE *p_spc = (TYPE *)malloc(szAlloc);

    *(OTHER_TYPE *)p_spc = some_value;  // CONSTRAINT VIOLATION 
    ...
    */

    memblk st_var;

    // Assigning (int) value
    st_var.x = 10;
    printf("value of x(int): %d\n", st_var.x);

    // Assigning (double) value
    st_var.y = 3.14;
    printf("value of y(double): %.2f\n", st_var.y);

    // Assigning (long long) value
    st_var.z = 1000;
    printf("value of z(long long): %lld\n\n", st_var.z);

    /*..............................................*/
    size_t szAlloc = sizeof(long long) > sizeof(double) ?
                     sizeof(long long) : sizeof(double);

    void *p_spc = malloc(szAlloc);

    // Assigning (int) value
    *(int *)p_spc = 10;
    printf("value of (int): %d\n", *(int *)p_spc);

    // Assigning (double) value
    *(double *)p_spc = 3.14;
    printf("value of (double): %.2f\n", *(double *)p_spc);

    // Assigning (long long) value
    *(long long *)p_spc = 1000;
    printf("value of (long long): %lld\n", *(long long *)p_spc);

    free(p_spc);
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t `sizeof(memblk)` work?

Comment: @Ryan I don't understand.

Comment: You have some logic to select `sizeof(long long)` vs. `sizeof(double)`, but can’t you use `sizeof(memblk)` to avoid all that?

Comment: @Ryan Sure. It would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of `long long` is by definition at least as large as the size of `int`, so the size allocated by `malloc()` is enough to hold all 3 types.

The C Standard guarantees that the pointer returned by `malloc()` is properly aligned for access with any of the standard types. Hence the above code is perfectly defined for each of the parts where you store a given type and retrieve it.

I cannot think of a reason why you would not be able to use the same memory for different uses in different parts of the program. Since you do not interlace the accesses via pointers to different types, nor try to reinterpret the representation of one type as another, I think the behavior of the whole sequence is fully defined.

Note however that you should test the return value of `malloc()`. On a system where `malloc()` would fail, the program would indeed have undefined behavior.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why a quality compiler would not allow a programmer to reliably use memory as different types in different parts of the program, as long as such uses are not interleaved.  GCC and clang, however, given something like `int *p1 = (int*)(myBuff + offset); useInt(p1); ...do other stuff... int *p3 = (int*)(myBuff + offset); useInt(p3);` will treat it as equivalent to `int *p1 = (int*)(myBuff + offset); useInt(p1); ...do other stuff... (int*)addressExpression; useInt(p1);` without regard for whether other pointers might have been derived from `myBuff`...

Comment: ...and used to access the associated storage between the last time `p1` was used and the time `p3` was created.  Since the Standard doesn't require compilers to recognize the derivation of lvalues and pointers as meaningful sequenced events, the authors of gcc and clang feel no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers, like gcc and clang when not using `-fno-strict-aliasing` to force them to comply with the C Standard, cannot reliably handle code that uses storage as different types at different times, even in non-overlapping fashion and in ways that don't actually involve aliasing.

If you're using a compiler that correctly handles cases that don't involve aliasing, then you should be okay provided that anything which will be done with a derived lvalue D, or anything derived from it, is done before any of the following occur:

1. The storage is accessed in conflicting fashion using an lvalue not derived from D (reads conflict with writes but not reads; writes conflict with both reads and writes).
2. An lvalue is derived, not from D, that will at some point in future be used directly or indirectly to access the storage in conflicting fashion.
3. Execution reaches the start of a function or loop wherein one of the above occurs.

Unfortunately, both gcc and clang ignore the timing of pointer and lvalue derivation, which means that they will often take code which wouldn't involve aliasing if performed as written and rewrite it in ways that introduce aliasing, while blindly assuming that no aliasing will occur.  For example, given the sequence:

1. Take address of someUnionArray[i].member1.
2. Use that pointer and then abandon it.
3. Take address of someUnionArray[j].member2.
4. Use that pointer and then abandon it.
5. Take address of someUnionArray[i].member1.
6. Use that pointer and then abandon it.

Both gcc and clang will keep the pointer from step 1 and reuse it in step 6, blindly assuming that nothing else has disturbed the object in question.  Reusing the result of the address calculation would be fine, but each operation that takes the address of a union member needs to be kept in sequence with regard to any preceding operations involving the same union object.

A compiler that can handle the proper semantics with unions shouldn't have any difficulty applying the same logic to pointer typecasts, but since gcc and clang can't even handle simple obvious cases, I don't think it's safe to use the default dialect in any situation where storage will ever be used as more than one type, even in ways the Standard would seem to be intended to allow.

(*) Note that technically, accessing a struct or union member using an lvalue of that member's type always violates N1570 p6.5p7 and thus invokes UB unless the member is of a character type, but such a reading would be absurd.  The only way struct and union types would make sense would be if an lvalue that is derived from a struct or union member can be accessed using the member type in cases where that lvalue isn't used in ways that, as written, would alias anything else.